# A good library for SFTP/FTP functionality for Scala?

Tags: sftp, scala

I've been checking out https://github.com/dacr/jassh and https://github.com/sirthias/scala-ssh

Neither seem to work...

Comment: Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information, then [edit] and define *good*.

Comment: Can you explain why they don't work? Is it because these libraries are lacking a needed feature? Do you need both FTP **and** SFTP support or would, say, a library just supporting FTP work? Please edit your question and read the [Question Quality Guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/133), thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that crossed my way, it's called Scala FTP. It's open source and available on GitHub. It does not look like it has support for SFTP but, at the time of this writing, you said in the title FTP/SFTP (FTP or SFTP). Note: This library hasn't been updated in two years.

## [Scala FTP (open source)](https://github.com/owainlewis/scala-ftp)

> A small library for working with FTP in Scala
>
> ```
> object E {
>
>   private val client: FTP = FTPClient() // create a new FTP client instance
>
>   def downloadFileExample() : Unit = {
>     client.connectWithAuth("ftp.mozilla.org", "anonymous", "")
>
>     client.cd("pub")
>
>     if (client.filesInCurrentDirectory.contains("README")) {
>       client.downloadFile("README")
>     }
>
>     client.disconnect()
>   }
> }
> ```